# I was unable to get past this while dual booting ubuntu on my windows 10 laptop

Tags: dual-boot

The image where the screen refused to move further.

checking./casper/filesystem.squashfs
wasn't moving ahead this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 1.4Gb file it's going to take sometime just leave it be.